# How to create a Django MPTT model with multiple trees

Tags: django, django-models, django-mptt

I am trying to create a structure where I have one model named "Company" and another model named "FSLI". The FSLI is an MPTT model.
Each FSLI must be mapped to a Company. Each Company can have multiple FSLIs.
Following is my code for FSLI model:

```
class Fsli(MPTTModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='parent_child')
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="company_fsli")

    ASSET = "asset"
    LIABILITY = "liability"
    EQUITY = "equity"
    INCOME = "income"
    EXPENSE = "expense"
    FSLI_TYPES = (
        (ASSET, "Asset"),
        (LIABILITY, "Liability"),
        (EQUITY, "Equity"),
        (INCOME, "Income"),
        (EXPENSE, "Expense"),
    )

    fsli_type = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=FSLI_TYPES, default=ASSET)
    remap_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rename_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delete_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unmapped_cat =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    statement = None
    if fsli_type == 'income' or fsli_type == 'expense':
        statement = 'pl'
    else:
        statement = 'bs'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.fsli_type} - {self.company}"
```

I want Django-MPTT to create separate tree structures for FSLI objects based on their 'company' field. For example, one tree of FSLI objects for company "foo" and another for company "bar" How do I do that?

Also, will I encounter any additional problems/limitations later when accessing and updating the trees using this approach, as compared to simple single tree structures?

Comment: You would have to control that the each company has only nodes descending from a root node which is not used by any other company. It might be clearer and more controllable if you are using a `ManyToManyfield` in company for the `Fsli` model, probably with its own dedicated `through` model that contains appropriate checks or even routines.

Comment: I get it. One root node for each company.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on comment by Risadinha

I created a root node for each Company. All nodes for each Company descend from the respective root node.